# Spring configuration - resource not found

Tags: java, spring

A method that i run inside my spring project uses a template but the template isnt being referenced/setup correctly by the looks of it.

This is my app-config.xml where i am trying to reference the file. It is the notifications.properties file that i am trying to reference. There is a file inside there that is being referenced in my code.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.company.application.util.spring.context.TypeConvertingReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60" />
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/components</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/messages</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/spring/i18n/errors</value>
                <value>WEB-INF/jsp/secure/support/messages</value>
                <value>com/company/application/notifications/notifications</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This is the relevant parts of the stacktrace i am getting

```
An error occurred during execution of handler: com.company.web.mvc.usermanagement.ViewUsersController#createRole(SystemUserDetailsDto, BindingResult, Model, SessionStatus)
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'en/newuserpassword.html'
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:352)
```

this is the file it is trying to reach which is used when creating a new user
`new.user.password.template=en/newuserpassword.html`

[image: folder structure here]